# Facebook share button in Android Application

Tags: android, google-chrome, facebook-messenger

FB share button could successfully oepn the FB messenger app in Chrome browser.

However, the same source code, it fail to open the FB messenger app if display in Android APP application, and this application display web page using Chrome browser inside.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide a custom `WebViewClient` implementation to your `WebView` that checks for facebook.com links (or whatever links you like) and then explicitly fire an `Intent` so others can pickup the `Action`, instead of allowing the WebView to handle it as it sees fit.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

            if (uri.getHost().contains("facebook.com")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);

                return false;
            }

        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }

});
```